# Enums Interoperability between Objective-C and Swift

Tags: objective-c, enums, swift

I am porting parts of my project to Swift and find out that enums are not interoperable.

Also any property's and functions that use an enum are not exposed to objective-c because enum doesn't have no equivalence at objective-c.

Even if the enum is of type NSInteger still the enum isn't exposed.

How to work around this Interoperability problem keeping swift class's as clean as possible?

Comment: You won't get all the functionality of Swift-native `enum` types, but one option is just to declare them using the `NS_ENUM` macro in Objective-C. Those are imported into Swift as an `enum` and accessible (obviously) from your Obj-C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 2:** In Swift 2 you can now expose enums to Objective-C. Make the enum non-generic, inherit from a simple numeric type (like `Int`), and don't use associated values. Then it will show up in Objective-C with the name of the enum pre-pended to the cases so it looks like an Objective-C enum.

edit: To be sure it shows up, annotate it with `@objc`. If there are any issues preventing it from bridging automatically you'll get a compiler error.

**Swift 1.x:**
The answer is you can't, at least not currently. If you want to interoperate with enums you need to declare them in Objective-C.

As Nate says, use `NS_ENUM` and Swift will pull the definition in as an `enum` and strip off the prefixes from the values.

Comment: Most probably is the best possible solution

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/macinsmith/SwiftObjcEnumExample) is a simple Xcode project that has Swift enums being accessed by objective C and objective C enums being accessed by Swift